# equivalent formula for getpivotdata() in excel to google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot-table

I am exporting my Excel spreadsheets into Google Sheets and use a lot of Pivot Tables. In Excel to take data from the Pivot Table I use the =GETPIVOTDATA function. Is there an equivalent in Google Sheets?

Comment: Did you check the [function list documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273)?

Comment: Yes, it seems no method to read pivot data in Google Docs .

Answer (score 2):

The best alternative I found was to use a VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP function instead of GETPIVOTDATA.  Example could be VLOOKUP("Wages", MyPivotTableName, 2, FALSE).  This would retrieve the 2nd column (let's say its "engineering" spend type) for the row "Wages" in the MyPivotTableName (set a Named range on it using Data -> Range).

Comment: thank you, this was really useful for me as I couldn't get my head around the GetPivotData docs at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6167538?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You may use google sheets it has the same function `GETPIVOTDATA`

Answer (score 1):

For some time, there is a [GETPIVOTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6167538?hl=en) formula. Works fine but different form excel's one. There is no auto-generate formula method while you point cell from pivot table. Instead you need to type it and add all arguments.